# How to get nested lists to display so that a child list appears beneath its parent in the stacking order?

Tags: css, html-lists, z-index

Here is a pen for reference:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/blwCI

How do I get a nested lists to appear lower in the stacking order compared to its parent?
I tried z-index with no success.

For example, a design calls for "Fourth Level" to appear beneath "Third Level".

Sample code:

```
<ul class="firstLevel">
  <li>First Level
    <ul class="secondLevel">
      <li>Second Level
        <ul class="thirdLevel">
          <li>Third Level
            <ul class="fourthLevel">
              <li>Fourth Level</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. When you increase the z-index of a parent then all the children increase by the same amount. Same thing if you try to position the parent, the children will move with the parent. You could only do this by unnesting the elements but that probably isn't what you want either.

You're probably going to have to add some extra markup to place your visual overlays without altering the parent-child relationships of the lists. eg;

```
      <li>Third Level
        <ul class="fourthLevel">
          <li>Fourth Level</li>
        </ul>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0">I'M ON TOP OF FOUR</div>
      </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You are right that what I wanted was not possible. I ended up just "faking" the stacking order by applying gradients and background colors to various elements. In the future, I may take your advice and do it the correct way (restructure the markup). For now, the time that it would take to do that is prohibitive.